# If I recreate a project with different frameworks should the projects have different repos or be different branches of the same repo?

Tags: git, github, frameworks, branch

So, if I decide to recreate a web application with a different frontend or backend framework altogether but the end result looks the same with the same functions then should will it be better to have both projects in different git repositories or in the same repository as different branches since they are essentiallly the same project?

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to keep them as separate projects. Every project has one master branch, but if you have one branch per framework then which branch is master is arbitrary, and you would have a number of branches that never merge to master. Keeping them as separate repos allows a more normal situation where master means something.

If you want to keep projects with different frameworks in your workspace simultaneously and go back and forth between them, it’s easier if they are in separate repos. if they are different branches then you have to checkout the project twice in different places. With separate repos you just checkout each project next to the others in the same directory.